# How do I draw the Quad image in LOVE2D?

Tags: lua, love2d

Im having problem in using textures in love2d and here's my code:

```
local angle = 0

function love.load()
    starboyAtlas = love.image.newImageData("Starboy.png")
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter("nearest", "nearest")
    starboy = love.graphics.newQuad(4, 3, 80, 142, starboyAtlas:getDimensions())
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(starboyAtlas, starboy)
end

---the error said that "texture expected, got ImageData"
function love.load()
    starboyAtlas = love.graphics.newImage("Starboy.png")
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter("nearest", "nearest")
    starboy = love.graphics.newQuad(4, 3, 80, 142, starboyAtlas:getDimensions())
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(starboyAtlas, starboy)
end
--the error is that "Quad expected, got nil
```

How do I fix this to draw my Quad?

Comment: Consider removing the question or posting an answer instead of writing "[SOLVED]" in the title. Questions in StackOverflow are here not only to help the authors, but also guide others who run into similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `love.graphics.newImage()` instead. Just insert the file into that function, then draw your quad in a way it's supposed to.